# Interactive curve fitting with MATLAB using custom GUI?

Tags: matlab, interactive, curve-fitting, least-squares

I find examples the best way to demonstrate my question. I generate some data, add some random noise, and fit it to get back my chosen "generator" value...

```
x = linspace(0.01,1,50);
value = 3.82;
y = exp(-value.*x);
y = awgn(y,30);

options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',1000,'MaxIter',1000,'TolFun',1e-10,'Display','off');
model = @(p,x) exp(-p(1).*x);
startingVals = [5];
lb = [1];
ub = [10];
[fittedValue] = lsqcurvefit(model,startingVals,x,y,lb,ub,options)
fittedGraph = exp(-fittedValue.*x);

plot(x,y,'o');
hold on
plot(x,fittedGraph,'r-');
```

[image: data and fit]

In this new example, I have generated the same data but this time added much more noise to the first 15 points. Because it is random sometimes it works out okay, but after a few runs I get a good example that illustrates my problem. Same code, except for these lines added under `value = 3.82`

```
y = exp(-value.*x);
y(1:15) = awgn(y(1:15),5);
y(15:end) = awgn(y(15:end),30);
```

[image: Noisy data fit]

As you can see, it has clearly not given a good fit to where the data seems reliable, because it is fitting from points 1-50. What I want to do is say, okay MATLAB, I can see we have some noisy data but it seems decent over a range, only fit your exponential from points 15 to the end. I could go back to my code and update it to do this, but I will be batch fitting graphs like this where each one will have different ranges of 'good' data.

So what I am after is a GUI callback mechanisms that allows me to click on two circles from the data and have them change color or something, which indicates the `lsqcurvefit` will only fit over that range. Internally all it has to change is inside the lsqcurvefit call e.g.

**x(16:end)**,**y(16:end)**

But the range should update depending on the starting and ending circles I have clicked.

I hope my question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: The app `cftool` has a function that does exactly this.

Comment: @Jommy Thanks, admittedly I jumped right past the `cftool`, mainly because I will be fitting more complex equations which it doesn't really support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ginput to select the two points for your min and max in the plot.

```
[x,y]=ginput(2); 
%this returns you the x and y coordinates of two points clicked after each other
%the min point is assumed to be clicked first
min=[x(1) y(1)];
max=[x(2) y(2)];
```

then you could fit your curve with the coordinates for min and max I guess. 
You could also switch between a rightclick for the min and a leftclick for the max etc.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: `ginput` was exactly what I was after, thanks. I should be able to work with this.